# What is the story of this image?

Tags: identification, contemporary-history, photography

I've seen this image a lot, particularly since the passing of Steve Jobs. I'm wondering if this is actually a photo of Steve before or after a presentation. Or, has there been a similar photo and this is just a mockup, because it looks so iconic?

If another photo served as a model to this one, would you be able to link to it?

[image: Steve Jobs and Apple]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is based on the standard Apple logo:

[image: Apple logo]

and was modified to incorporate the silhouette of Steve Jobs to commemorate his death in 2011 by Hong Kong based Graphic Designer, [Jonathan Mak Long](http://www.jonmak.com/About).

[image: Steve Jobs]

Comment: Thanks. Was it made by Apple?

Comment: If you right click and search google on the image it has an article crediting the creator, first thing that comes up.